# SQL : Error at Union All in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my  query. I am using UNION ALL because i need to bring data when MONTH column is both NOT NULL and NULL.
But this is not working, i am wondering why.

```
    SELECT metricname,
         careertrackid,
         monthyrname,
         SUM(metricvalue) AS metricval,
         CASE
           WHEN MONTH IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR) + LPAD(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH),2,'0')
           ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalyear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalquarter)
         END AS dispmonth
  FROM atp_9375_forecast,
       vspforecasts
  WHERE ibfcollectionid = vspforecasts.ibfid
  AND   (YEAR>= 2018 AND MONTH>= 7)
  GROUP BY careertrackid,
           metricname,
           dispmonth,
           monthyrname
  ORDER BY dispmonth

UNION ALL

SELECT metricname,
         careertrackid,
         monthyrname,
         SUM(metricvalue) AS metricval,
         CASE
           WHEN MONTH IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR) + LPAD(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH),2,'0')
           ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalyear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalquarter)
         END AS dispmonth
  FROM atp_9375_forecast,
       vspforecasts
  WHERE ibfcollectionid = vspforecasts.ibfid
  AND   (YEAR>= 2018 AND MONTH IS NULL)
  GROUP BY careertrackid,
           metricname,
           dispmonth,
           monthyrname
  ORDER BY dispmonth
```

Is there any other way in which i can still apply MONTH filter but that should include both NULL and NOT NULL as MONTH column is having both these values in table.

**Sample Result**
This is the desired result but this only comes when MONTH column includes NULL and NOT NULL

```
{"201806":"0.00","201807":"0.00","201808":"0.00","201809":"0.00","201810":"0.00","201811":"0.00","FY19Q2":"0.00","FY19Q3":"0.00","FY19Q4":"0.00","FY20Q1":"0.00"}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question your `union all` two queries are almost the same, only in the `month` to judge, you don't need to use `UNION ALL` just use add a condition  `(MONTH>= 7 OR MONTH IS NULL)` in `WHERE`

```
SELECT metricname,
     careertrackid,
     monthyrname,
     SUM(metricvalue) AS metricval,
     CASE
       WHEN MONTH IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR) + LPAD(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH),2,'0')
       ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalyear) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,acnfiscalquarter)
     END AS dispmonth
FROM atp_9375_forecast INNER JOIN 
   vspforecasts ON ibfcollectionid = vspforecasts.ibfid
WHERE (YEAR>= 2018 AND (MONTH>= 7 OR MONTH IS NULL))
GROUP BY careertrackid,
       metricname,
       dispmonth,
       monthyrname
ORDER BY dispmonth
```

**Note**

I suggest avoid to use `,` comma to connect tables, because it's an old style, you can use `join` instead of it.

Comment: oops....this did the trick. But can u please tell why this UNION ALL was having issues.

Comment: Because `UNION ALL` will get duplicate rows in your query if the row appears in first and second query.